# Combining video with several audio files

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I need to combine several audio files with a video file. Each audio file should have a specific volume, time and delay. Combined as a whole it works fine. The problem arises with the volume of the music. Despite setting `volume=0.1` for the first audio file, the volume keeps increasing (fade in effect). I've tried probably everything to remove this, but none of the ways I've found works. What else can I try? Is there any other tool I can use for this?

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i 2.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1.0[a];[1]atrim=0:10,adelay=0|0,volume=0.1[b];[2]atrim=0:10,adelay=20000|20000,volume=0.1[c];[a][b][c]amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=1000:normalize=0,dynaudnorm[mix]" -map 0:v -map "[mix]" out.mp4
```